# How do I model a List of the same Entity in hibernate for a User? (Session, SessionHistory)

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am making a Spring Boot Application with ORM.

I have a user, which has a current session. So modelling these two with @Entity is working great.

We have a Table Users, and Sessions. So a User is an Entity, Session is an Entity. in addition to the current session field that is mapped by a @OnetoOne. There is a SessionHistory class we'd like the user to have. And we would like it to essentially be what it's called. it has all the previous history.

Which brings me to my problem. I don't need to model that in the ERD, I think? So I can't just have it in there. Typically it would be a query that would select all session that have that user's id. How would I translate that into Java code?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

   @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
   private Long id;

  ...

   @Transient
   private SessionHistory sessionHistory;
   
   public User(...) {
      ...
      // this.sessionHistory = new SessionHistory();
   }

   public User() {

   }
}
```

I don't know what to try. Because I think it's not a good idea to have a table (it just doesn't make sense to me).

What I did think of, but discussion with my team said it was gonna be a problem. But I suggested Something to do with the SessionRepository, since that's our gateway to the database, but that violates the architecture if I'm not mistaken. TO have that attribute instantiated that way using either the service or repository.

Comment: try to use custom query with db operations and model that query result.

Comment: Can you give an example please? I feel like it would be very helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to make a PostLoadEventListener and check for my entity type. That way I can make a query and set the list of sessions on User load.

[Resource that helped a lot](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/) It is a little old so just be sure to research the new way of doing things

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).